# Integral Convergence with exponential function

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

For the following integral,

$
 \int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{f(x)} dx},
$

Can we have a necessary and sufficient condition on $f(x)$ to affirm that this integral is convergent or divergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to consider the following.

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{f(x)}dx=\int_0^ae^{f(x)}dx+\int_a^{\infty}e^{f(x)}dx$$

You want the first integral to be finite, so it shouldn't be too hard to pin down what conditions you need on $f$. Now, for the integral on $(a,\infty)$ you need to make sure that the behavior of $f$ is going to be so that $e^{f(x)}\to0$ so you want $f(x)$ to be negative, and decreasing, negative alone won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: @wafa, No problem! You can also hit the up arrow to the left of the answer to indicate that it meets your approval.